# How to find the average slope of two lines?

Tags: geometry

Consider de image below as reference. Given two lines (Line A and Line B) defined as:

Line A: $y = (-2)x + 10$

Line B: $y = (0.525)x + 0.475$

How to calculate the "Middle Line"? The Middle Line divides the space between Line 1 and Line2 in two equal sub-spaces. By *calculating the Middle Line* I mean having the values of $a$ and $b$ that define it, like:

Middle Line: $y = ax + b$

By inspection, the Middle Line in the example figure is approximately:

Middle Line: $3x + (-8.81)$

In this example the lines have an intersect, but they could be parallel as well.

[image: Example of the middle line]

Comment: do you mean you want to find the equation of the line which bisects the obtuse angle between the lines A and B and passes through their intersection point?

Comment: Average means you find arithmetic mean of two slopes?

Comment: @DavidQuinn, yes, a good way to put it.

Comment: @Vasya I tried that already, but as you can see by the example picture, 3 is different than the average between -2 and 0.525. It's more like the half of the angle between Line 1 and Line 2.

Comment: There are $2$ such angular bisecting lines, perpendicular to each other. To get one of them, starting from $y=mx+b, y=nx+c$, let $M$ = tan( (arctan($m$)+arctan($n$)/$2$) for the slope of a middle line, next get intersection $x_0=(c-b)/(m-n), y_0 = mx_0 + b$ and then the line is $y - y_0 = M (x - x_0)$

Comment: @AlexSC: if you want slope of the bisector, remember that slope is a tangent so you can use something like this: $\text{slope} =\tan(\frac{\tan^{-1}\text{slope}_1+\tan^{-1}\text{slope}_2}{2})$

Comment: @AlexSC: that's because there are two bisectors which are perpendicular to each other. So the other bisector will have slope =$\frac{-1}{\text{slope}}$. Just pick the one you need.

Comment: @Vasya, correct, the other slope calculates to 3.10, close to the one I found by inspection. I'm now after the intersept of that line.

Comment: @Ned, thanks for your comment, it seems to agree with Vasya and indeed goes to the right direction, however I did not understand how to calculate the intersept from your equations.

Comment: @Ned, what I did was to use the intersection point of the Line 1 and Line 2 and then I could find the $b$ for the Middle Line. It workded fine, Middle Line is given by $y = (3.10)x + (-9.25)$, approximately, but I wonder if there is a better way because calculating the intersection of two lines if a bit more CPU intensive than I would like. Any ideas?

Comment: @AlexSC  The "naive" intersection computation has just one division and one multiplication, I don't know if you'll be able reduce that. If it's the trig that you want to avoid, that should be possible using tangent of a sum and some half angle formulas that I certainly don't remember  but you could find them and probably write an algebraic formula for the slope of the middle line without any trig in it.

Comment: @Ned post your answer and I will take it.

Comment: @Vasya post your answer and I will take it if you post it before Ned.

Comment: @AlexSC: I posted it, glad I was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope of the bisector, can be calculated using the slopes of two given lines. The slope is a tangent so we can calculate the slope in question using something like this: $$\text{slope of a bisector}=\tan(\frac{\tan^{−1}slope_1+\tan^{−1}slope_2}{2})$$
Keep in mind that there are two possible bisectors which are perpendicular to each other so the other slope will be negative reciprocal of this slope.
You can also see that if lines are parallel, they will have the same slope to find the equation of the bisecting line you can just take arithmetic mean of two given lines.
Finally, to find point of intersection if lines are not parallel, just equate the expressions of the given lines and solve the resulting equation for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

You want the locus of the points $(x,y)$ that are equidistant from both lines.

Therefore if the lines are $a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1 = 0 $ and $a_2 x + b_2 y + c_2 = 0$

Then, this locus has the equation

$ \dfrac{ a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1 }{\sqrt{ a_1^2 + b_1^2 }} = \pm \dfrac{a_2 x + b_2 y + c_2}{\sqrt{ a_2^2 + b_2^2 } }$